# Need help understanding how \n, \b, and \r will render printf output

Tags: c, language-lawyer

I wrote the following program in the C and when I run it, I was surprised by looking at the output.

Here is the program

```
int main()
{    
       printf("\nab");
       printf("\bsi");    
       printf("\rha");    
}
```

The output is :- hai
whereas I was expecting "absiha" since \n is for new line, \b is for backspace(non erase) and \r is for carriage return. So I was expecting that curson would be at "i" character because \r has been applied but when I run it and saw the output I was totally surprised and confused. Can anyone please explain me the output?

Comment: It could be operating system specific.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Let's take it one step at a time:

`<new line>ab<backspace>si<carriage return>ha`

First, handle the backspace.  Note that even though it is "non-erase", the next character to be output would overwrite what was backspaced over:

`<new line>asi<carriage return>ha`

Now, a carriage return means to go back to the beginning of the line.  So the "ha" overwrites the "as" in "asi:

`<new line>hai`

Now, the cursor is currently sitting on the `i`, so the next character to be output would overwrite `i`.

Comment: you mean backspace would just move cursor one position before? just like an insert statement ?

Comment: @ankur.trapasiya  I'm half-guessing that's what you meant by "non-erase", but I've seen it before in other contexts - like, if I have terminal output in a long running program, then hit backspace on the keyboard, the cursor moves over but the character itself stays there until new output is put on top of it.  No clue what you mean by "like an insert statement".

Answer (score 10):

Visit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C

`Escape Sequence    Character
\a  Bell (speaker beeps)
\b  Backspace (non-erase)
\f  Form feed/clear screen
\n  New line
\r  Carriage Return
\t  Tab
\v  Vertical tab
\\  Backslash
\?  Question mark
\'  Single quote
\"  Double quote
\xnn    Hexadecimal character code nn
\onn    Octal character code nn
\nn Octal character code nn`

Comment: thanks for informative answer. Probably you should read the question first.