# printf delete content with \r in C

Tags: c, string, tokenize

in C, I'm doing a tokenizer. I'm in trouble because I've noticed that if I type:

```
printf ("String of text\r");
```

all that is writed before `'\r'` is not printed.

So, if I want to TOKENIZE `"String of text\r"` , the last token should be `"Text"`, and no, its `" ext"`

Anybody know why?

edit: code here. If i print args[0], args[1]... and Im char[] str = "cadena de texto\r"

```
#include <stdlib.h>
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <string.h>

        int
        detectpattern(char target)
        {
            int patternsize;
            int contador;
            int found;
            char pattern[] = {'\t', '\r', ' ', '\n', '  '};

            patternsize = sizeof(pattern)/sizeof(char);
            contador = 1;

            while (contador <= patternsize) {
                if (pattern[contador] == target) {
                    found = 1;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    found = 0;
                }
                contador++;
                }
            return found;
        }

        void
        ispattern(char *str, int *inword){
            if (*inword != 0) {
                *inword = 0;
                *str = '\0';
            }
        }

        void
        isword(char *str, int *inword, char **args, int *words){
            if (*inword == 0) {
                *inword = 1;
                args[*words] = str;
                *words = *words + 1;
            }
        }

        int
        mytokenize(char *str, char **args, int maxargs) {
            int i;
            int intword;
            int intwords;
            int * inword = &intword;
            int * words = &intwords;

            intword = 0;
            intwords = 0;
            i = 0;

            if (!str[i]) {
                printf("String no válido");
                exit(0);
            }

            while (str[i] != '\0') {
                if (detectpattern(str[i])) {
                    ispattern(&str[i], inword);
                } else {
                    isword(&str[i], inword, args, words);

                }
                if (*words == maxargs) {
                break;
                }
                i++;
            }
            return *words;
        }

        enum{
            maxargs = 2,
        };

        int
        main(int argc, char *argv[]){
            char str[] = "cadena de texto";
            char *strptr = &str[0];
            char *array_punteros[maxargs];

            mytokenize(strptr, array_punteros, maxargs);

            exit(0);
        }
```

Comment: Please post the tokenizer code.

Comment: This seems to be 2 different questions? Do you want to know about printing a string or tokenizing a string ?

Comment: Also, `\r` is carriage return, maybe take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253250/need-help-understanding-how-n-b-and-r-will-render-printf-output)

Comment: im asking about tokenizing a string, but this is my problem. \r is one of the patterns .. im posting the code wait. It works with the other patterns.

Answer (score 0):

`\r` is Cariage Return. It causes your terminal emulator to move the cursor to the begining of the line - and may be even erases the line. Try printing to a file and opening it with an editor like vi or emacs.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("aaa test\r");
    printf("bbb test\r");

}
```

produces just `bbb test` on the terminal.

Tested with gcc 4.9 on cygwin.

Comment: It won't erase the line.

Comment: Yes, nothing is printed because there is no `'\n'` and no `fflush()`.

Comment: `fflush` doesn't help, for some reason. but `printf ("String of text\r\n");` works, which means `\r` is not erasing the line.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Then there must be some more output to erase all up to `ext`. Or my guess is wrong